# Flutter: List out all the images stored on the device

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages, flutter-image

I am creating a camera app where I am almost finished but there is just one thing missing from my arsenal... I want to list out all the images that is stored on the device inside a listview but I have no idea how to do this. My code is error free the only I want is to know how I can do this propably without using the **image_picker** plugin although I don't know if it can perform this job but I am not a fan of this plugin for I am going towards something custom made.

Comment: `photo_manager` gives you that

Comment: Just the images or image paths alone if I want right???

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/photo_manager/latest/photo_manager/PhotoManager/getAssetPathList.html